# How to handle extreme outlier in the prediction of Random Forest Regression Model

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, prediction, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I have done Prediction by using Random Forest Regression and I have got r2score of 90% which is good for this dataset I guess, after checking MSE I got more than 1500 as result of mse. Then I checked the difference between Actual and predicted value, there I found that my model was predicted only one value very poorly and so the mse error is too high. Now how to handle the only one value that is been predicted very poorly by my rfr model?

In my training set I have similar kind of data as well and so my model should have learnt from that, but somehow my prediction for that only one value is poor? What is the problem?